# dimension of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

How can I prove that the splitting Field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt2)$ over the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ is two dimensional vector space over $\mathbb{Q}$ ?

Comment: In the text, $\mathbb{C}$ should be $\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: @Adam: Comments suffice, especially since those were *just* made.

Comment: @AsafKaragila thanks for the heads up on timing. I saw the comment and thought it would be helpful, but then got side-tracked writing an answer rather than completing a good edit, which is a my-bad.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show that $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ is a basis.

Answer (score 2):

It is isomorphic to $\Bbb Q[x]/(x^2-2)$, since the polynomial has degree $2$, the vector space dimension is $2$.

---

If you don't know this fact, it's easy to see by  since a polynomial has reduction modulo $(x^2-2)$ given by

$$p(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{N_1} a_{2n} x^{2n}+\sum_{n=0}^{N_2}a_{2n+1}x^{2n+1}$$

$$\overline{p(x)}=\sum_{n=0}^{N_1} a_{2n} 2^{n}+\overline{x}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{N_2}a_{2n+1}2^{n}\right)$$